# Zephyr RTOS: Enabling C++ Exceptions

Tags: c++, cmake, zephyr-rtos

I'm trying to enable C++ Exceptions for Zephyr (Version 3.2.99). [The documentation only states, that CONFIG_EXCEPTIONS must be enabled.](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/3.2.0/develop/languages/cpp/index.html#language-features)

**Where do I have to enable cpp exceptions, so that `-fno-exceptions` is not passed?**

I enabled it in the CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.0)
set(BOARD xiao_ble)
find_package(Zephyr)
project(my_project)
# ...
target_sources(app PRIVATE
        src/main.cpp
# ...
        )
target_compile_options(app PRIVATE -fexceptions)
```

and in the KConfig (prj.conf):

```
# CPP
CONFIG_CPLUSPLUS=y
CONFIG_EXCEPTIONS=y
# ...
```

but still a `-fno-exceptions` is passed when building the project.

Comment: check CMAKE_CXXFLAGS

Comment: @Jonathan I added `MESSAGE("$ENV{CMAKE_CXXFLAGS}")` at the end of the CMakeLists.txt to check, but it seems to be empty.

Comment: also check CMAKE_LDFLAGS and CMAKE_CCFLAGS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't read the CMake output properly. The KConfig in the question produces the following warning: `warning: EXCEPTIONS (defined at subsys/cpp/Kconfig:76) was assigned the value 'y' but got the value 'n'. Check these unsatisfied dependencies: LIB_CPLUSPLUS (=n).`

This is because enabling the `CONFIG_EXCEPTIONS` requires `CONFIG_LIB_CPLUSPLUS` to be enabled and `CONFIG_NEWLIB_LIBC_NANO` to be disabled, as stated in the [KConfig options documentation](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/3.2.0/kconfig.html#CONFIG_EXCEPTIONS). After adding these two configurations to the `prj.conf` file like this:

```
# CPP
CONFIG_CPLUSPLUS=y
CONFIG_NEWLIB_LIBC_NANO=n
CONFIG_LIB_CPLUSPLUS=y
CONFIG_EXCEPTIONS=y
# ... any other configurations
```

exceptions can be thrown.